# What's the best python implementation for mapReduce pattern?

Tags: python, mapreduce

What's the best Python implementation for `MapReduce`, a framework or a library, probably as good as Apache `hadoop` one, but if only it's in Python and best in terms of good documented and easy understanding, fully implemented for `MapReduce` pattern, high scalability, high stability, and lightweight.

I googled one called `mincemeat`, not sure about it, but any others well known?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

There are some pieces here and there if you search for them. For example [Octopy](http://code.google.com/p/octopy/) and [Disco](http://discoproject.org/) as well as [Hadoopy](https://github.com/bwhite/hadoopy).

However, I don't believe that any of them can compete Hadoop in terms of maturity, stability, scalability, performance, etc. For small cases they should suffice, but for something more "glorious", you have to stick to Hadoop.

Remember that you can still write map/reduce programs in Hadoop with python/jython.

EDIT : I've recently came across [mrjob](http://packages.python.org/mrjob/index.html). It seems great, as it eases the way to write map/reduce programs and then launch them on Hadoop or on Amazon's Elastic MapReduce platform. The article that brough the good news is [here](http://musicmachinery.com/2011/09/04/how-to-process-a-million-songs-in-20-minutes/)

Answer (score 4):

Update in 2019:
Would highly recommend [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/).

===

Another good option is [Dumbo](https://github.com/klbostee/dumbo/wiki/Short-tutorial).

Below is the code to run a map/reduce for word counting.

```
def mapper(key,value):
  for word in value.split(): yield word,1
def reducer(key,values):
  yield key,sum(values)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  import dumbo
  dumbo.run(mapper,reducer)
```

To run it, just feed your text file `wc_input.txt` for counting, the output is saved as `wc_output`.

```
 python -m dumbo wordcount.py -hadoop /path/to/hadoop -input wc_input.txt -output wc_output
```

Answer (score 2):

You should also look at Mrs: http://code.google.com/p/mrs-mapreduce/

It is particularly well-suited for computationally intensive iterative programs.